# OpenVPN config - Authentication username password

Tags: openvpn

I use a VPN provider (tigerVPN) and they use OpenVPN with data channel cipher AES-256-CBC. For authentication, they use username/password and server cert.

I'm assuming that config doesn't support perfect forward secrecy?
Would an attacker be able to decrypt recorded data streams if he is able to obtain username/password? Is this configuration unsafe?

Comment: @Kindle Q I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like 'hi' and 'thanks'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333).

Answer (score 1):

Does your configuration have a `tls-client` and `tls-auth key` settings?
If not, your assumptions are correct and yes, an attacker could decrypt content of previously captured data streams. He would need the complete blockchain captured as well and some know clear text.

Comment: thank you for your response.

this would be the config:

client
remote vie.tigervpn.com 1194 udp
remote vie.tigervpn.com 443 tcp-client
pull
auth-user-pass password.txt 
comp-lzo adaptive
ca ca.crt
dev tun
tls-client
script-security 2
cipher AES-256-CBC
mute 10
remote-cert-tls server